# Split tab delimited data into arrays

Tags: arrays, perl, split

I need to split data in columns separated by the tab delimiter for input example (row 1): `abc<tab>def<tab>ghi` so that each column is put in a different array.

Can I achieve this using `split('\t')`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you want to do as you provide no reference code. However, this will at least crudely do what I think you want. Take an input file (better to read in assuming it's longer that the one provided) and for each line in the array holding the input, split on `\t` and push the first element onto `@group1` etc. You should be able to print out each element from there...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict; 

open my $infile, '<', 'in.txt' or die "Can't read from $file: $!";

my (@group1, @group2, @group3);

while (<$infile>){
    my @cols = split(/\t/);
    push @group1, $cols[0];
    push @group2, $cols[1];
    push @group3, $cols[2];
}   

print "$group1[0]\n";
print "$group2[0]\n";
print "$group3[0]\n";
```

Output:

```
abc
def
ghi
```